# What is the return type of constructor in C++

Tags: c++

In C++, Syntactically a constructor doesn't have any return type.
But what it actually returns.
Does it returns void or object of class type?

Answer (score 3):

The standard (Constructors 12.1/10 **class.ctor**) says:

> No return type (not even void) shall be specified for a constructor. A return statement in the body of a constructor shall not specify a return value.

The second sentence implies that constructors return nothing.

Comment: +1 for quoting the standard.

Comment: So what's the difference between returning nothing and returning void?

Comment: @starsplusplus No difference

Answer (score 2):

It really returns nothing, this is not a trick statement. It is just used to construct an object in an (already) allocated space. To return something it has to create something, and the constructor doesn't create it, just sets the params of an object; the space isn't its own.